# Question about the definition of an algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Curit.png)

I understand the operational definiton of an algebra homomorphism ($f$ is a K-linear ring homomorphism).
But I don't see how this definition is implied by the the fact that $ f \circ \eta_A=\eta_B$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!! You will find people are more likely to answer your questions if they are self contained, we shouldn't have to click through links in order to understand your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the map $\eta_A$ is that it defines the scalar multiplication on $A$ as a $K$-vector space. In particular, for $\lambda \in K$ and $a \in A$, we define scalar multiplication by
$$
\lambda\cdot a := \eta_A(\lambda)a,
$$
where the right hand side is just a product in the ring $A$. Now, for a map $f:A \to B$, the condition that $f \circ \eta_A = \eta_B$ means that for $\lambda\in K$ and $a \in A$, we have
$$
f(\lambda\cdot a) = f(\eta_A(\lambda)a) = f(\eta_A(\lambda))f(a) = \eta_B(\lambda)f(a) = \lambda\cdot f(a),
$$
so $f\circ \eta_A = \eta_B$ makes $f$ a $K$-linear transformation (the other properties of $K$-linear multiplication come from the fact that $f$ is a ring homomorphism).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.